# Symfony 5 - internationalized routes - prefix routes with empty or dynamic locale

Tags: routes, locale, symfony5

The following declaration is working:

```
app_localized:
    resource: "../src/Controller/"
    type: annotation
    prefix:
        en: '' # don't prefix URLs for English, the default locale
        de: '/de'
        es: '/es'
```

So we can visit the following urls:

- /
- /de
- /es

But I don't want to update every year the config file for this project, when supported languages change. I want to declarate the route as follows:

```
app_localized:
    resource: "../src/Controller/"
    type: annotation
    prefix:
        en: '' # don't prefix URLs for English, the default locale
        '*': {_locale}
```

So it would be possible to visit the following urls:

- /
- /de
- /es
- /nl
- /fr
- and much more

But sadly that doesn't work. Would be also great to define the locale as pattern:
`^[a-z]{2}([-])?([A-Za-z]{2})?$`

Any ideas how to solve this?

Answer (score 1):

I usually define two routes: one for unprefixed routes, another for prefixed

Something like this may work

```
app_localized:
  resource: "../src/Controller/"
  type: annotation
  prefix: '/{_locale}'
  name_prefix: 'localized_'

app_default:
  resource: "../src/Controller/"
  type: annotation
  prefix: '/'
  name_prefix: 'default_'
  defaults:
    _locale: en
```